# I need to use Laravel Passport authentication for micro services running across multiple servers and domains,

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, microservices, laravel-passport

I have micro services running across multiple servers and domains, I need them all to authenticate to one server, I am using Laravel Passport for my API authentication,
the "Laravel\Passport\Passport::scopesFor(['place-orders', 'check-status']);" is vital to my service since it will limit the times consumer need to authenticate and check access level.

what is the best way to go about doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general industry term for what you want is "single sign-on" so you might have more luck searching by that term.

There is a simple package by Jasney for SSO at https://packagist.org/packages/jasny/sso and although I have not used it myself, it seems popular.

I hope this helps set you on the right track.